# Using VBA code to get pivottable to update automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with some data in one sheet and then a pivottable based on the data in the table in another sheet. I would like the pivot table to update every time the table is updated with some new data. The table and pivottable should remain in different sheets.

The code below only works when the table and the pivottable are in the same sheet. Can anyone help?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("Pivottabel1").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub
```

Sincerely
Christian

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`?

Answer (score 0):

Bender's answer would work, and your code works for me, I would check your refences.

1. Is the event you are using, "Worksheet_Change", in the sheet that contains the table?
2. Is "Sheet1" the sheet that contains the Pivot Table?
3. Is the Pivot Table named "Pivottabel1" as you have written in your code?